# Removing tags in title

Tags: discussion, tags, editing, titles

I just removed 5 (scheme) tags from 5 questions. Some examples:

- Before: **(Scheme) [SICP ex. 1.30]
  Iterative Sum**
- After: [**[SICP ex. 1.30] Iterative
  Sum**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1535/2254)

They were all in the similar format:

- Before: **(Scheme) [SICP ex. 2.85] Implement a system for raising and lowering objects in a tower of types**
- After: [**[SICP ex. 2.85] Implement a system for raising and lowering objects in a tower of types**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2322/2254)

My reasoning for this is the [following question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88991/157047) I asked on meta.SE:

> ... I'm still wondering
>   whether it would be a good idea to
>   reenforcing no tags in the title as a
>   convention. Personally I find the tags
>   clear enough, but as long as there is
>   no convention to follow, some people
>   will edit questions to remove the
>   tags, and other could actually add
>   them to the title.

The accepted answer points to an answer to a related question someone asked on [Game Development](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/428/5227):

> Personally I hate this. If it's
>   important, work the tag into the
>   question grammatically, e.g. "How do I
>   color my model in OpenGL?", "How do I
>   change the color of a texture in
>   Cocos2d?". If you're just going to
>   slam ungrammatical tags on it, well,
>   we have tags for that.

On which Jeff answered the following:

> correct, this is my guidance -- if the
>   tag works "naturally" in the title,
>   use it there. If it does not, then the
>   most popular tag is added to the HTML
>   on the page anyway, so you're covered
>   in either case.

I saw a lot of tagged titles passing by the past few weeks, and believe it would be a good idea to edit them when you see them to prevent its usage from spreading.

Comment: can you clarify / summarize the specific before and after in the above "I just.."

Comment: @Jeff: Done. You could argue it would better to add "in Scheme" at the end of the question. In that case I surely wouldn't have edited it, but I still somehow feel that's redundant data. P.s.: I wrote questions like that myself, so I have no definite opinion on that. :)

Comment: I agree to the idea of fixing the title of new and recent questions, as long as we don't go about re-awakening old posts just for this.

Comment: @Brian: Agreed, they were all on the front page. I decided to leave the older ones as they were.